# SSLHandshakeErrorTracker : SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL connection.Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired

Tags: java, ssl, websphere, sslhandshakeexception

There are 2 servers. The 1st one is production env and 2nd is my Websphere (Mock server). I have installed an application in Websphere which is not able to process the https/http request from the client server.

When the client configure to access the **https** (port 9443) to my mock server then I am getting the following error on request processing:

> ERROR 13172876 --- [bContainer : 13]
> c.i.w.s.c.impl.SSLHandshakeErrorTracker  : SSLC0008E: Unable to
> initialize SSL connection.   Unauthorized access was denied or
> security settings have expired.  Exception is
> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext
> connection?

When the client configures **http** (port 9080), then I am getting the following error:

> WARN 13172876 --- [ebContainer : 7] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound
> : Request method 'GET' not supported
>
> ERROR 13172876 --- [ebContainer :
> 7] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error
> page for request [/] as the response has already been committed. As a
> result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your
> application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able
> to resolve this problem by setting
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

I have configured the WireMock application for service virtualization in my application. My application has 1 RestController which has 2 request methods(POST) and 1 class to configure/run wiremock service. I do not have any error when I test the application directly from Mock server. But when the client hits my server, I am getting the following error.

Answer (score 0):

For https issue, the certificate may get expired which is configured @ Application Server (Websphere) level.

For Http issue, there may be some other firewall or configuration which executes the request before it goes to server. Otherwise, it should create issue @ your local setup as well.